# I painted over rust with rust-resistant paint. A few days later it's back. How can this be possible?

Tags: pipe, rust-removal, rust-proofing

I have this pipe through my kitchen.

I painted the pipe with rust-resistant paint and in a few days was back.
Could it be rust? Could it be some kind of mold? It's quite extruded/"3d" if I may say that. This is what makes me wonder whether it's actually something else than rust.

[image]

More photos of the thing are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5xcv0pjzak9yqzj/AADP6JQUAwbScwm3VvtmPPDta?dl=0

Comment: Did you remove the rust before painting?  Rust is usually loose so just painting over it will cause the paint to fall off in places.

Comment: Looks like a bad case of paint-proof rust...

Comment: I've read from multiple sources that you can paint over rust if ti's rust-resistant paint... I did clean as well as I could (scratched with a dry cloth), but did not sand, or use any special cleaning solution.

Comment: @mircealungu you have to remove any loose flakes and similar.

Comment: Is that pipe under pressure? Heating system perhaps? That looks like a tiny leak to me and (rusty?) sediment accumulating at the leak point.

Comment: By not removing all possible rust , a paint coating may accelerate rust by holding moisture , Don't believe the advertisements.

Comment: @Olivier - I'll ask the neighbors what's the pipe for. I don't know :( But for sure there's no visible leakage; unless it's microscopic and whatever water escapes is immediately coopted in the rust formation?!

Answer (score 2):

The metal expands when it rusts. This is what leads to the 3D-effect. This also means that it spalls, and comes off in flakes. The surface has very little structural integrity left.

Remove all loose rust with a steel wire brush before painting. Otherwise the paint will peel away with rust flakes.

This can be seen in the user manual for many products, such as this [more or less randomly selected one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Stops-Rust-12-oz-Flat-Rusty-Metal-Primer-Spray-7769830/202056392):

[image: SURFACE PREPARATION Remove all dirt, grease, oil, salt and chemical contaminants by washing the surface with a commercial detergent, or other suitable cleaning method. Rinse with fresh water and allow to thoroughly dry. Remove loose paint and rust with a wire brush or sandpaper.]

Comment: If "rust-converting" paint is used, one should NOT remove all the rust before painting.  Just scrape off the loose stuff.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, which is why I write *Remove all loose rust*.

Comment: As much rust as possible must be removed ( power brush, blast, hand brush) before applying conversion coating ( phosphoric acid base with manganese) for best service.

Answer (score 2):

Any remaining trace amounts of rust will enable and accelerate further rust forming.

Best to **first scrape/sand/brush off what you can**. If you can get it 100% bare you can just apply a rust inhibitor, such as a "rust resistent paint".

For this step you can use a machine sander or metal spin brush (a *brush wheel* or *metal cup*) mounted to a drill.

If not completely bare, due to an uneven surface with dimples or rivets, or due to unreachable areas, **apply a "rust converter"**. This is a safe water based solution, and it is not the same as a rust inhibitor.

Then **paint with a rust inhibiting paint or rust inhibiting primer**. A primer is used if the paint colour you want is not available as rust inhibiting paint.

If removing your rust results in undesirable ditches or flat spots you can use a two-part automotive **filler** (like "Bondo") to fill and smoothen where needed.

Answer (score 1):

### The paint didn't stick because the surface was not prepared.

If you want paint to stick, you need 2 things:

- A physically sound surface that will not spall off, because if a layer of the substrate fails, the paint will fall off. That generally involves sanding, filing, grinding or wire brushing.
- A non-contaminated surface so there will not be a film of an incompatible chemical between substrate and paint.

So I don't think you had either one because you didn't clean off the rust.  Who knows what was trapped under the rust?

As far as the paint, I am skeptical about "rust resistant" claims.  Certainly the claim is only valid if you follow the instructions, which may require a rust-free surface to start with.

There is not a silver bullet solution to rust. [NASA has been looking](https://corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov).  Someone, probably Nikita Kruschkev, located their primary space center right on the ocean, where it gets ridiculous amounts of corrosion from sea spray.

The only thing they have found that gets what I would call acceptable results is either power wirebrushing or needle scaling or media blasting, followed by quality primer. Ideally a mil-spec zinc chromate, but I find Rustoleum 7769 performs reasonably well if the prep is *tip top*.

But if you're looking for a paint product *which will replace* surface prep, that is not a thing, sorry.